# Tabulator - Change style of checkbox within the row selection column

Tags: tabulator

I want to change the checkbox styling within the tabulator row selection column. I'm using bootstrap 4 for css. I'm trying to add custom css class to checkbox via jquery but with no luck.

```
        var table = new Tabulator("#job_openings_table_wrapper", {
          data: tableData,
          selectable: true,
          height: "420px",
          pagination: "local",
          paginationSize: 10,
          paginationSizeSelector: [10, 20, 50, 100],
          footerElement:
            "<div id='record-count-container' class='table-footer-element'><label>Total Records:</label><span id='record-count' class='ml-1'>#</span></div><div id='selected-record-count-container' class='table-footer-element'><label>Selected:</label><span id='selected-record-count' class='ml-1'>#</span></div>",
          dataFiltered: update_record_count,
          dataLoaded: update_record_count,
          rowSelectionChanged: update_selected_record_count,
          rowContextMenu: rowContextMenuBuilder,
          columns: [
            {
              formatter: "rowSelection",
              titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
              align: "center",
              headerSort: false,
            },
            { title: "Job ID", field: "job_id" },
            { title: "Position", field: "position" },
            { title: "Employment Type", field: "employment_type" },
            { title: "Hiring Department", field: "hiring_department" },
            { title: "Created On", field: "created_on" },
            { title: "Status", field: "status" },
          ],
        });

        $(":checkbox").wrap("<div class='custom-control custom-checkbox'></div>");
        $(':checkbox').addClass('custom-control-input');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dosnt work because Tabulator uses a virtual DOM, this means that only the elements for rows actually visible currently exist, the rows are created and destroyed as the user scrolls or changes pages.

This means that you cannot safely manipulate the table contents from outside the table.

The good news is, Tabulator already comes with a way to add a class to the cell, which should do what you need. you can then tweak your selector to work on inputs inside cells with this class.

In your column definition for the row selection column you would need to add the `cssClass` property, in this case we will set it to use the "custom-checkbox-cell" class:

```js
{
    formatter: "rowSelection",
    titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
    align: "center",
    headerSort: false,
    cssClass:"custom-checkbox-cell",
},
```

You can then style the checkbox with the following CSS selector:

```css
.custom-checkbox-cell input{
    border:2px solid blue; //add a blue border to the checkbox
}
```

Comment: If you found this helpful would you mind marking it as the answer so others can find it more easily